# Using RecyclerView.OnScrollListener in RecyclerView to implement loading more items got duplicated items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I was trying to fetch JSON data into a RecyclerView using Retrofit 2. I also implemented pagination. Now for testing, I changed the JSON URL as if it will only show `5`items per page. The page number can be changed by adding "&page=`PAGE#`" at the end of the JSON URL (where PAGE# is integer value starting from 1 and if no Page no is mentioned, it will show by default the first page).

**The Problem:** I have successfully added every page into the Recyclerview. But, it is adding the last page items twice, sometimes it is adding 3 times.
 Like this:
**It will add last post couple of times**[image]

I am unable to find the problem. The step by step debugging does not help. Please help me.  I am learning these so if you help me I would really appreciate it.

WPPOST POJO:

```
public class WPPost {

  @SerializedName("code")
  @Expose
  private String code;
  @SerializedName("id")
  @Expose
  private Integer id;
  @SerializedName("guid")
  @Expose
  private Guid guid;
  @SerializedName("title")
  @Expose
  private Title title;
  @SerializedName("content")
  @Expose
  private Content content;
  @SerializedName("post_categories")
  @Expose
  private List < String > postCategories = null;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Guid getGuid() {
    return guid;
  }

  public void setGuid(Guid guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
  }

  public Title getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(Title title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public Content getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  public void setContent(Content content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  public List < String > getPostCategories() {
    return postCategories;
  }

  public void setPostCategories(List < String > postCategories) {
    this.postCategories = postCategories;
  }
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

MODEL Class:

```
public class Model {

  public int postid;
  public String title;
  public String content;
  public String categoriesnames;
  public Model(int mID, String mTitle, String mContent, String mCategorynames) {
    this.postid = mID;
    this.title = mTitle;
    this.content = mContent;
    this.categoriesnames = mCategorynames;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check your responses from server?

Comment: yes. I have checked the responses. It is all ok. No duplicate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RecyclerView`'s `onScrolled` method might be called many times during a short time, and your if statement cannot prevent the `getRetrofit()` from being called multiple times at a single scroll, you can print a log message with your request url to verify this.

So, you should fix the issue by eliminate the redundant duplicated requests. For example, check if a `getRetrofit` request is working in progress using a flag:

```
public void getRetrofit() {

  isLoadingData = true; // <--- flag

  // ....

  final Call < List < WPPost >> call = service.getPostInfo(url);
  call.enqueue(new Callback < List < WPPost >> () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call < List < WPPost >> call, Response < List < WPPost >> response) {
      isLoadingData = false; // <--- flag
      // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call < List < WPPost >> call, Throwable t) {
      isLoadingData = false; // <--- flag
    }
  });
}
```

Then, use this flag to determine if a next page request should be fired.

Comment: Yes! I think this is the more appropriate solution. Thank you so much @Hong Duan I really appreciate your help.